# Unable to edit/set focus to input(text box) present in REACT-SELECT menu list

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There are 2 components one is Input component and the other is Status component which has REACT SELECT dropdown.The React select component has a MENU list which has the input filed inside it.

Problem: Unable to edit/set the focus in to the input(text box) that is present inside the react select menu list.

Below mentioned are the 2 components

```
//SELECT dropdown component
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import IStatus from "./status.type";
import IStatusLookUp from "./statuslookup";
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import StatusService from './status.service';
import ProgressIndicatorCardComponent from "../../../components/LodaingIndicator";
import Menu from "./statusAutoSuggestionMenu";

const Status = (props :any) => {
  const [status, setstatus] = useState<Array<IStatus>>([]);
  const [statuslookup, setstatuslookup] = useState<Array<IStatusLookUp>>([]);
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [isStatusDataPresent, setisStatusDataPresent] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState<string>("");
  const selectRef:any = useRef(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const inputRef:any = useRef('');

  const onDomClick = (e:any) => {
    let menu = selectRef.current.querySelector(".wk-react-select__control");

    if (
      !selectRef.current.contains(e.target) 
      ||
      !menu ||
      !menu.contains(e.target)
    ) {
      setIsFocused(true);
      setInputValue("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", onDomClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", onDomClick);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    GetAllStatusMapping(props.workstreamtypeguid);
  }, []);

  const GetAllStatusMapping = async (workstreamtypeguid :string) => {
    await StatusService.getAllStatusMapping(workstreamtypeguid)
      .then((response: any) => {
        setLoading(false);
        let obj = response.data.data.filter((item :any) => item.workstreamCategoryId === workstreamtypeguid);
        if(obj.length > 0) 
        {
          setErrorMsg('');
          setisStatusDataPresent(true);
          setstatus(obj); 
          GetAllStatusLookup(props.workflowcategoryid);  
        }else{
          setisStatusDataPresent(false);
          setErrorMsg("There are no Workstream status available for the Category - " + props.workstreamCategory + ".");
        }
        
      })
      .catch((e: Error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setErrorMsg("There are no Workstream status available for the Category - " + props.workstreamCategory + ".");
        setisStatusDataPresent(false);
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  
  const GetAllStatusLookup = async (workflowcategoryid :number)=>{
    await StatusService.getStatusLookUp(workflowcategoryid)
    .then((response:any)=>{
      setstatuslookup(response.data.data);
    }) 
    .catch((e: Error) => {    
      console.log(e);
    });
  }

  const filterstatuslookup =  [...statuslookup]
  filterstatuslookup.unshift({
    firmID: 0,
    categoryId: 0,
    statusId: 0,
    statusName: '--Select--',
  })

  function ifDataNotPresent() {
    return (
      <div className="w-60 m-auto mt-3">
        <div className="d-flex flex-grow-1 wk-banner-warning wk-p-16 d-flex mb-3 NoMappingData">
          <span className="wk-icon-filled wk-icon-filled-caution me-2 text-secondary-wkOrange-base "></span>
          <div className="col-lg-11 col-11 col-sm-11">
            <div className="wk-font-size-13"><strong>Warning</strong>
            </div>
            <div className="wk-font-size-14">{errorMsg}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
   
const getFormatedV2 = (label: any, userInput: any) => {
  // Highlight letters
  return label
    ?.split(' ')
    .map((word: string) =>
      word
        .split('')
        .map((c: string) =>
          userInput.toLowerCase().includes(c.toLowerCase()) ? (
            <strong className="fw-bold">{c}</strong>
          ) : (
            c
          )
        )
    );
};

// Custom components for highlight on search
const Option = ({ children, getValue, ...props }: any) => {
  const userInput = props?.selectProps?.inputValue || '';
  const label = props?.data?.label || '';
  return (
    <components.Option {...props}>
      <div>
        {userInput?.length
          ? label?.split(' ').length
            ? getFormatedV2(label, userInput)
            : label
          : label}
      </div>
    </components.Option>
  );
};

const handleOnChange =(e: any, workstreamStatusId:any)=>{
  setIsFocused(false)
  let datareplica :Array<IStatus> = [...status];
  let modifiedObj = datareplica.find(
    (obj) => { return obj.workstreamStatusId === workstreamStatusId}
  );
  if(modifiedObj !== undefined){
      modifiedObj.workflowStatus = e.label
      modifiedObj.workflowStatusId = e.value
      setstatus(datareplica);
  }
}

  return (
    
    <div className="w-60 m-auto mt-4 pheight">
       {
        isStatusDataPresent? 
        <div className="row mb">
          <div className="col-lg-6 col-6 col-sm-6">
            <p className="heading-Worksteps">Workstream Staus</p>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-6 col-6 col-sm-6">
            <p className="heading-Worksteps">Workflow Status</p>
          </div>
        </div>: null
      }

{loading? <ProgressIndicatorCardComponent/>: isStatusDataPresent ? 
    <div>
      {status?.map((data,index) => {
        return (
          <div className="row mb-3" key={index}>
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-6 col-sm-6">
              <Form.Group controlId="form1">
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={
                    data.workstreamStatus === ""
                      ? "Default value"
                      : data.workstreamStatus
                  }
                  disabled
                  readOnly
                />
              
              </Form.Group>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-6 col-sm-6"  ref={selectRef}>                   
            <Select
              id={data.workstreamStatusId}
              key={index}
              menuPlacement="auto"
              menuShouldScrollIntoView={false}
              menuPortalTarget={document.body}
              styles={{ menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
              isSearchable={true}              
              options={
                filterstatuslookup.map((data, index) => {
                  return {
                    label: data.statusName,
                    value: data.statusId,
                    key: index
                  };
                })
              }
              value={
                  data.workflowStatus !== null ?{
                    label:data.workflowStatus,
                    value:data.workflowStatusId,
                    key:index
                  }: {
                    label:'--Select--',
                    value:0,
                    key:index
                  }
              } 
              components={{
                Menu: ({innerRef,children, ...props }) => (                  
                  <Menu {...props} selectRef={selectRef}>
                    {children}
                  </Menu>
                ),
              }}
              className="wk-react-select-container"
              classNamePrefix="wk-react-select" 
              onChange={ (e) =>
                handleOnChange(
                  e,
                  data.workstreamStatusId
              )}     
            />               
              </div>
          </div>

        )
      })}

    </div> :   
      ifDataNotPresent()
      }
  </div>
  
  )
};

export default Status;
//Input Component
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { components } from "react-select";
const { MenuList } = components;

const Menu = ({ innerRef, selectProps, ...props }: any) => {
  const inputRef:any = useRef('');
  const { inputValue, onInputChange, onFocus } = selectProps;

  const [textInputValue, setTextInputValue] = useState('');

    return (
      <div  style={{width:'100%'}}>
        <components.Menu {...props}>
          <div  style={{width:'100%'}}>
          <div>{props.children}</div>
            <div className="w-100 m-auto" style={{float:'left', backgroundColor:'#F6F6F6', borderTop:'1px solid #DADADA'}}>
            
                <div className="row mb-2" style={{paddingLeft:'2%', paddingTop:'1%', paddingBottom:'1%'}}>
                  <div className="col-lg-9 col-9 col-sm-9">
                   
                      <Form.Label style={{height:'9px'}}>Auto Suggestion</Form.Label>
                       <input 
                        type="text" 
                        id={selectProps.id}
                        ref={inputRef}
                        style={{width:'100%'}}
                        autoCorrect="off"
                        autoComplete="off"
                        spellCheck="false"
                      /> 
                      
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-lg-3 col-3 col-sm-3" style={{marginTop:'6%', float:'left', marginLeft:'-3%'}}>
                  <button className="wk-button outline-none active">Save as New</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            
            </div>
          </div>
        </components.Menu>
        
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default Menu;
```